# Issue with some product images in product page

Tags: product-images

As the video below, Some products's images are not appears in the product page, but if I press f5 they will appear somehow.

I guess that happened after I run this command:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Video link: https://streamable.com/rvavgn

Website: https://femascu.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cab you please try these commands :

```
bin/magento in:rein 
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento s:d:c 
bin/magento s:s:d -f
```